# How to split the value of a BYTE register into two nibbles in SMS32v50 assembly?

Tags: assembly

I am getting an ASCII value from the keyboard, e.g. `l` is pressed on the keyboard, so the value in AL will be 4Ch. I want to split this value into two separate values.

So, in this example: 4 and C.
I am using sms32v50 assembler code.

Comment: What's sms32v50?  Is that some kind of x86?

Comment: @PeterCordes Looks like an 8086 simulator.

Comment: @fuz: not exactly.  http://www.softwareforeducation.com/sms32v50/sms32v50_manual/020architecture.htm says it only has 4 GP registers, AL, BL, CL, DL.  So it's missing SI and DI, and BP.  Also the top half of the GP regs, unless you use the 16-bit version of the ISA.  http://www.softwareforeducation.com/sms32v50/sms32v50_manual/245-IsetSummary.htm lists the instructions.  It doesn't include a shift by more than 1 bit.

Comment: @PeterCordes I see.  Shit like this is why I usually don't make assumptions.  Have removed my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Voilà:

```
    JMP Start       ; Skip past the data table

    DB "0123456789ABCDEF"   ; Hexadecimal characters

Start:

    CLO             ; Close unwanted windows.

Rep:
    IN  00          ; Wait for key press - Store it in AL.
    CMP AL,0D       ; Was it the Enter key? (ASCII 0D)
    JZ  E           ; Yes - end.

    PUSH AL         ; Save AL (restore it with POP)

    SHR AL          ; Isolate high nibble (four shifts)
    SHR AL
    SHR AL
    SHR AL

    ADD AL, 2       ; 02 is start address of data table
    MOV AL, [AL]    ; Copy data from table to AL
    MOV [C0], AL    ; Write character to VDU

    POP AL          ; Restore AL
    AND AL, 0F      ; Isolate low nibble

    ADD AL, 2       ; 02 is start address of data table
    MOV AL, [AL]    ; Copy data from table to AL
    MOV [C1], AL    ; Write character to VDU

    JMP Rep         ; Repeat the procedure

E:
    END
```

Comment: Interesting.  It's like an 8-bit x86 with stripped-down instruction set. http://www.softwareforeducation.com/sms32v50/sms32v50_manual/245-IsetSummary.htm. And yeah, looks like it doesn't have an `[AL+2]` addressing mode.  Instead of push/pop AL, I might have just copied AL to another reg like CL.

Comment: @PeterCordes: The assembler did not allow me to  do`MOV CL, AL`, but instead referred me to PUSH/POP.

Comment: Oh wow, yeah it apparently is missing mov reg, reg.  I guess the other option is `mov cl, 0xf` / `and cl, al`